# Compile ILONLY=0 32BIT=1 in Visual Studio 2010 Express (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, 32-bit, corflags

How can I make VB.NET (Visual Studio 2010) compile an assembly with PE32, ILONLY=0, and 32BIT=1?  Or must I continue to post-process it with corflags.exe?

I'm starting to get the impression this is an unusual combination of flags, but it's the only way I've found to run an old app that includes a signed, 32-bit, legacy DLL for which it is prohibitively expensive to get an updated version.

x86 sets the 32BIT flag, of course, but also sets the ILONLY flag.  And that causes a load error on the DLL.

I don't know all the entry points for the DLL, so I don't know how I'd write a wrapper for it.

The original application is from VS2003.  Has there been a change since then that would automatically create a viable wrapper if I somehow removed and re-added the DLL?  So far, I've gotten to VS2010 through successive upgrades and their automated project conversions.  I need to be careful not to break something I can't fix about this DLL's integration to VS or the app.